# Can't connect to network: issue with routing?

Tags: networking, routing

I'm having the hardest time connecting my Ubuntu Server to the network, and I have a feeling it's because I'm not routing properly. Can anybody help me out?

Network configuration provided by network administrator:
IPv4: xxx.xxx.xxx.150
Subnet: xxx.xxx.xxx.128/25
Gateway: xxx.xxx.xxx.129
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.128
Fully-Qualified Domain Name: aaa.bbb.ccc.com
DNS Nameserver1: X
DNS Nameserver2: Y
DNS Nameserver3: Z

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto p5p2
iface p5p2 inet static
    address xxx.xxx.xxx.150
    gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.129
    netmask 255.255.255.128
    network xxx.xxx.xxx.128/25
    broadcast xxx.xxx.xxx.255
    dns-domain ccc.com
    dns-search ccc.com bbb.ccc.com
    dns-nameservers X Y Z

$ ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:12493 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12493 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:685849 (685.8 KB)  TX bytes:685849 (685.8 KB)

p5p2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:c0:bf:f3  
          inet addr:xxx.xxx.xxx.150  Bcast:xxx.xxx.xxx.255  Mask:255.255.255.128
          inet6 addr: xxxx::xxx:xxxx:xxxx:bff3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:164475 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1827 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:15147287 (15.1 MB)  TX bytes:137569 (137.5 KB)

$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         xxx.xxx.xxx.129 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 p5p2
xxx.xxx.xxx.128 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.128 U     0      0        0 p5p2

$ ping -c 4 xxx.xxx.xxx.129
PING xxx.xxx.xxx.129 (xxx.xxx.xxx.129) 56(84) bytes of data.
From xxx.xxx.xxx.150 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From xxx.xxx.xxx.150 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From xxx.xxx.xxx.150 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From xxx.xxx.xxx.150 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable

--- xxx.xxx.xxx.129 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, +4 errors, 100% packet loss, time 2999ms
pipe 3

$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   localhost
xxx.xxx.xxx.150 aaa.bbb.ccc.com aaa
```

Comment: what's the output of `ping www.google.com` and `arp -a` - can you see the MAC address of the gateway after pinging it?

Comment: Pinging google returns either `No route to host` or `Destination host unreachable` (I can't remember which but will check when onsite in the morning) and arp returns `(incomplete)` for the gateway after pinging it.

Comment: Is this a VM or physical host? Is there any network security? Check with your Network Administrator (and recheck the IP of the gateway). Of course, check all that @davidgo mentioned.

Comment: It's a physical host. There are two firewalls filtering inbound traffic but not outbound traffic. I have double checked the network configuration and gateway address with them multiple times. I'm starting to convince myself that they plugged me into the wrong switch or something else ridiculous like that. Would I be able to check that in any way via tcpdump or some other tool?

Comment: if you have a working host on the same network and you are able to exchange the cable from the working one, then you could see if it is on the switch if there is no additional port security which would prevent this. you can check the cable if you have a e.g. a laptop to which you could directly connect it (of course you should set up a similar netowrk setup on the laptop's network interface and at least one network card should be able to use autosense to correctly identify the sending/receiving pair or just connect the server and laptop to some SOHO switch/router just to see if it will work)

Comment: Sadly my unit is located at a colocation center, so I have no access to the switch. Additionally the cable in question is 10Gb fiber connection, and I don't have any other computer that can connect to it. The colocation service tells me the switch and fiber are both in working order, but they have been very difficult to work with, which makes me question if they really checked.

Answer (score 0):

This is most unlikely to be a routing problem - more likely a cable or driver fault.

The first step is to see if you can ping the gateway (xxx.xxx.xxx.129).  If you can do this you can look at routing, if not, you need to look at a lower level - and I think the problem is at a lower level.

Comment: I can't ping the default gateway, it says `Destination Host Unreachable`. The NIC (AOC-STGN-i2S) is using the proper built-in driver (ixgbe). Can the cable be busted and still pass packets to tcpdump that are reasonable? What other lower level areas should I look at?

Comment: Outgoing packets go through tcpdump before they hit the wire, so they will look fine to TCPDump.  If incoming packets are OK on TCPDump I don't know what to advise.  Immediately after pinging the gateway, inspect your ARP table - does it show an entry for the gateway ?

Comment: It returns `<incomplete>` for the gateway arp address. The link lights on the NIC appear to flash nominally. How do I only capture all inbound packets with tcpdump, even if the destination isn't my IP?